# How to avoid repeatng for loops in Java?

Tags: java, loops, methods, refactoring

I have a code that works fine, but it looks too big as it has repetitive line of codes, can someone help me to make it shorter?

```
public void writeToFile(String file)
{
    try
    {
            PrintWriter pWrite = new PrintWriter(file);
            pWriter.println("[Auto data]");
            for (Auto line : autoMap.values())
            {
                if (line instanceof Auto) 
                {
                    String getLine = line.writeData(file);
                    pWrite.println(getLine); 
                }
            }
            pWriter.println();
            pWriter.println("[Nature data]"); 
            for (Nature line : natureMap.values())
            {
                if (line instanceof Nature) 
                {
                    String getLine = line.writeData(file);
                    pWrite.println(getLine); 
                }
            }
            pWriter.println();
            pWriter.println("[Sport data]");
            for (Sport line : sportMap.values())
            {
                if (line instanceof Sport) 
                {
                    String getLine = line.writeData(file);
                    pWrite.println(getLine); 
                }
            } 
            pWriter.println();
            pWriter.println("[Animal data]");
            for (Animal line : animalMap.values())
            {
                if (line instanceof Animal) 
                {
                    String getLine = line.writeData(file);
                    pWrite.println(getLine); 
                }
            }
            pWrite.close();
    }
    // catch block omitted
}
```

writeData method example **class Sport**:

```
public class Sport
{
     // codes omitted

    public String writeData(String file)
    {
        return title + type + cost + location;
    }
    // codes omitted
}
```

As you have noticed the for loops are necessary to subdivide data in order when writing to a file, but doing so, it made the code longer and repetitive, I cannot think of an efficient way to make it shorter.

Comment: What is the `writeData` method? It seems like it should be part of an interface, which means that you could put one loop in a method and call it with each map.

Comment: Do `Nature`, `Sport`, and `Animal` implement the same interface that defines the `writeData(...)` method?

Comment: Can you provide me with an example, please?

Comment: An example? You wrote the `writeData` method, is it in an interface? Or if you're not sure, add an example to your question.

Comment: Oh ignore that, that's just a call to the method of each specific class object. (e.g. it retrieves all fields values through the method `writeData`).  I will put an example.

Comment: It's definitely relevant. As you can see by all the answers, they recommend having that method as an interface method that is shared between the classes with the same functionality. That's the only obvious way to reduce the repetition in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a classic case when you can take advantage from Interface and Inheritance. In particular, I would define an interface which all class can inherits.

Then, I would define a private method in the same class where `writeToFile` is, which implements just the for loop on a given `Line`.

Finally, you can simply invoke that method in the `writeToFile` for each map. However, I would change a bit the implementation, as it is best practice to use the try-with-resource block, which guarantees to always close your stream before leaving the block, even in case of possible exception.

To give you an idea of what I am referring to, here is an example of possible implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

interface Line {
    String getType();
    default void writeData(PrintWriter pWrite) {
        pWrite.println("I am a " + getType());
    }
}

class Auto implements Line {
    public String getType() {
        return "Auto";
    }
}

class Sport implements Line {
    public String getType() {
        return "Sport";
    }
}

class Animal implements Line {
    public String getType() {
        return "Animal";
    }
}

public class Test {
    private Map<String, Line> itemMap;
    
    public Test() {
        initMap();
    }
    
    private void initMap() {
        itemMap = new HashMap<>();
        itemMap.put("auto1", new Auto());
        itemMap.put("sport1", new Sport());
        itemMap.put("animal1", new Animal());
    }
    
    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
        
        new Test().writeToFile("Test.txt");
    }
    
    public void writeToFile(String file) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter pWrite = new PrintWriter(file);) {
                writeLineToFile(pWrite, itemMap);
        }
        // catch block omitted
    }
    
    private void writeLineToFile(PrintWriter pWrite, Map<String, Line> map) {
        for (Line line : map.values()) {
            //Common part
            line.writeData(pWrite);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the file:

```
I am a Sport
I am a Animal
I am a Auto
```

In my opinion that appears cleaner and it is also much easier to maintain.

Surely, that is just an idea, you can personalize and add more things according to your needs, and in particular, by taking advantage of inheritance, the possibilies are limiteless.

Comment: I wrote down the code quickly, so i forgot to put the Key type. Assuming that the key is a String (you can have whatever you want there), you can define the values as "Line" type, the interface I showed you above. In this way, you can always add a value which is a subtype of Line, so you can generalize your map and use it for all types you need (Auto, Sport, Animal), or whatever class implements Line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if gather all those classes in a single Map collection say `itemMap`, how would I apply that in this context?

Comment: If you make all your classes implement the 'Line' (or 'WritableLine' :) ) interface, you can surely add all values in one single Map, it will work fine at least when it comes to write a line in the file in common format. However, If you need to do something different for each class, you can always define a method in the interface, implement it in different way in each class and invoke it. I am going to add this idea in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am still new to using the interface class, but I have made all those classes Auto, Nature, Sport and Animal be inherited by one class, so I avoid repeating hashMap for each class.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, we all started from the scratch with OOP and Java, and we are happy to help :)

Comment: When I type the collection type `writeLineToFile(pWriter, itemMap);` it gives me an error (incompatible type and it can not be converted from Map<String, Sport> to Map<String, Line>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231716/discussion-between-the-liner-and-marco-tizzano).

Answer (score 7):

Ensure `Nature`, `Sport`, and `Animal` all implement an interface such as:

```
public interface Writable {
    public String writeData(String file);
}
```

And since all of the elements of each Map implement the interface, the duplicate code can be extracted, and pass the Map to the new method which uses the interface:

```
public void writeToFile(String file) {
    PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(file);

    pWriter.println("[Auto data]");
    writeDataToFile(file, pWriter, autoMap);

    pWriter.println();
    pWriter.println("[Nature data]");
    writeDataToFile(file, pWriter, natureMap);

    pWriter.println();
    pWriter.println("[Animal data]");
    writeDataToFile(file, pWriter, animalMap);

   pWrite.close();
}

// assuming the map key is a string
private void writeDataToFile(String file, PrintWriter pWriter, Map<String, Writable> data) {
    for (Writable line : data.values()) {
        String getLine = line.writeData(file);
        pWriter.println(getLine); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Andrew interestingly enough, we had the same idea, but you got 2 upvotes and i got the "nothing". that's weird isn't it? :/

Comment: @Eritrean - good point - added an assumed  key!

Comment: three now, and i am going to upvote you as well :D

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks for your answer, what if gather all those classes in a single Map collection say `itemMap`, how would I apply that in this context?

Comment: Similar approach - the values in the Map would all have to conform to the type the Map may hold  - either all of the items implement a common interface or all extend a base class.